# why don't python classes need __new__

Tags: python, oop

I've been reading about the difference between a python constructor (`__new__`) vs. an initializer (`__init__`) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859129/python-and-python-c-api-new-versus-init).

Given that `__new__` is used to **create** class instances, and `__init__` is used to **customise** those instances.

Why do most examples & working code of python classes built only with `__init__`?

Examples [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Object_Oriented_Programming.html#composition) and [here](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/) (search "5. Classes")

Comment: When you initialize an object with `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` by issueing `newObj = MyClass(*args, **kwargs)`, Python already did the job of creating it for you with `__new__` and `self` is a reference to the new object. More info in the duplicate.

Comment: Note that your classes inherit the default `__new__` from `object`, and most of the time that's adequate, unless you're doing stuff like deriving from one of the built-in types.

Comment: @timgeb. Thought it was other way round. From py3's `__new__` doc: `If __new__() returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked like __init__(self[, ...]), where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to __new__().

If __new__() does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will not be invoked.
`

Comment: I don't see anything in that quote that implies it would be the other way round.