# Subclassing Tuple with str for init

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, tuples, subclass

I'm trying to create a subclass of `tuple` which behaves in all aspects like a normal `tuple` with the exception that I initialize it with a string which is automatically split first by the constructor (I also want its `__str__()` to join this again, but that's not the issue here).

I thought this to be straight-forward and tried it like this:

```
class C(tuple):
  def __init__(self, text):
    super(C, self).__init__(text.split(':'))

  def __str__(self):
    return '[%s]' % ':'.join(self)

c = C('one:two:three')  # I expect this to be like ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

So I try to pass a `text` (a `str`), split that and call my superclass's constructor with the result.  I expected to get a result like for `tuple([ 'one', 'two', 'three' ])`, i. e. a tuple of words: `('one', 'two', 'three')`.

But instead I get a tuple of characters, i. e. for the input `'one:two:three'` I get a `('o', 'n', 'e', ':', 't', 'w', 'o', ':', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e')` which is exactly the result I get when I call `tuple('one:two:three')`.

I debugged the situation and found out that my code gets properly executed (my `__init__()` gets called and calls the other `__init__()` with the correct values).  I also tried to replace the `super` construct by a concrete `tuple.__init__(self, text.split(':'))`, but that didn't change anything.  I also tried passing a `tuple` instead of the `list` created by `split()`, also no change.  Actually, calling super's `__init__()` does not seem to have any effect.  The interpreter still initializes the tuple with the string I pass originally.

Am I missing something?  Why is this not working as expected?  How can I create a class `C` which is a subclass of `tuple` and which I can initialize by calling `C('one:two:three')` to get an instance of `C` which is a tuple like `('one', 'two', 'three')`?

Comment: Which version are you using? I get `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` on 3.5

Comment: @StevenSummers: I'm using Python 2.7 in this project but I'm curious: Do you really get this error message about `object.__init__()` taking no arguments when you inherit `tuple` in 3.5?

Comment: That is what I receive when running your code, same for 3.4 and 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tuples are immutable,  use `__new__` instead of `__init__`:

```
class C(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, text):
        return super(C, cls).__new__(cls, text.split(':'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '[%s]' % ':'.join(self)

c = C('one:two:three')
print(c)
print(list(c))
```

Comment: For anyone wondering what's the difference between `__init__` and `__new__` this post really helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859129/python-and-python-c-api-new-versus-init