# What does cls in __new__ act as?

Tags: python

recently I'm leanring about python magic method,  in `__new__` we always rewrite it by

```py
class A:
    def __new__(cls):
        # ......
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        # .....
```

this method will return an A object then A will execute `__init__`.
so, I try the following script

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__')
        self.a = 20


class B:
    def __new__(cls):
        print('B.__new__')
        return super().__new__(A)

    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__')
        self.b = 30


t = B()
print(type(t))
```

then I get result

```py
B.__new__
<class '__main__.A'>
```

In my opinion, `B.__new__` return an A object as it shows, then it should execute `A.__init__` method, but in fact neither `A.__init__` nor `B.__init__` executed, object `t` is an A object but it have nothing relate to  A or B, this confuse me, what does `cls` in `__new__` method act as?

Comment: It's an abbreviation of *class*.

Comment: It is interesting that neither `__init__` method is executed. You're doing something that wouldn't usually be done: calling `__new__` in B to instantiate A, where the two classes are unrelated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new

Comment: Also see [Python (and Python C API): \_\_new\_\_ versus \_\_init\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859129/python-and-python-c-api-new-versus-init)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my opinion, `B.__new__` return an A object as it shows, then it should execute `A.__init__` method

That assumption is incorrect. Let's look at the code that creates instances. In python this would be the `type.__call__` method. The C implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L1076)

The three interesting steps that happen are:

1. call `type.__new__(type, ...)` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0rc1/Objects/typeobject.c#L1116))
2. abort when the return value of `__new__` is **not** a sub class of the `type` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0rc1/Objects/typeobject.c#L1123))
3. call `__init__` on the created object ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0rc1/Objects/typeobject.c#L1128))

Or in python code:

```py
# t = B() is roughly equivalent to

t = B.__new__()  # which returns `A.__new__()`
if ìssubclass(type(t), B):  # False
    t.__init__()  # never called
```

Your implementation of `B.__new__` however creates an object of type `A`. Because of that the `issubclass` check fails and no `__init__` is called.

To summarize: `B.__init__` is not called, because `B.__new__` did not create an object of type `B` and `A.__init__` was not called, because the class object `A` was not responsible for creating the instance (`B` was).

The end result is, that `t` is an instance of class `A` but its `__init__` was not called. That's why `t` is not *initialized*.