# How does default built-in class methods __init__ and __new__ look like?

Tags: python

When we create a python class, sometimes we did not define `__int__()` for it. So, when creating instance, under the hood, built-in `__init__` and `__new__` will be called.

```
class ABC:
    attr1=models.CharField...
    attr2=models.TextField...
    attr3=models.CharField...
```

When `abc = ABC(attr1=.., attr3=.., attr2=..)` is executed, in order to find out how those initial arguments are passed in and create instances, I have been searching for a few hours to find out how does default built-in class methods **`__init__`** and **`__new__`** look like, but failed.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: That looks like a Django model, which is decidedly different from a regular class, since it has a [metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ad6bb20557f5c87de26aeb3afb061af942a8cc17/django/db/models/base.py#L72) that deals with those fields. Are you talking about a plain class, or a Django model class? (You can find `__init__` for Django models [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ad6bb20557f5c87de26aeb3afb061af942a8cc17/django/db/models/base.py#L426).)

Comment: Additionally, for your example, `abc = ABC(attr1=.., attr3=.., attr2=..)` will raise a `TypeError: ABC() takes no arguments`, since your example has no overridden `__init__`.

Comment: The builtin `object.__new__`/`object.__init__` would be somewhere in C code presumably, if you used the CPython flavour. Would that really help you? Basically, by default it doesn't do anything except return an instance of your class, and it doesn't accept any arguments by default (as pointed out above).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python (and Python C API): \_\_new\_\_ versus \_\_init\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859129/python-and-python-c-api-new-versus-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a class it inherits from `object`. Basically, when you don't define `__init__` method in your class, the `object.__init__` is used. And you cannot get Python source code for that one becouse it's implemented with C - **PyObject_Init**. You can find the definition -
[PyObject_Init on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/196b53eb1e62871ca80dee180e4891b4dd5c52ac/Objects/object.c#L161)