# Custom class to represent sets of length 1

Tags: python

I would like to write my own class `Singleton` that represents a set of size 1. It should

1. subclass `frozenset` so that all the usual set operations work seamlessly between `Singleton`, `set`, `frozenset`, and
2. add an assertion to `__init__` of `frozenset` that checks that the underlying set is constructed on an iterable of length 1.

What is a clean way to do this? Subclassing? Decorators? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: If you only fix it in the constructor there would be nothing preventing you from adding more elements later

Comment: An immutable "set" of length 1 could be represented by a simple tuple…?

Comment: @mousetail Good point, I'll use a `frozenset` instead.

Comment: @deceze Yes, but I would like all the usual set operations to work. e.g.`(1,) | {2, 3, 4}
` fails.

Comment: Presumably you want `Singleton | Set` to yield a Set, not a Singleton or an error? I'd subclass `frozenset`, and override `frozenset.__init__()` to add the assertion and call super's (i.e. frozenset's) `__init__()`.  Have you tried that? What problems did you encounter?  It seems like your answer is in your question, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: @SarahMesser Yes that was my first thought, and no you didn't miss anything. I didn't encounter a problem, but I was looking for advice from someone experienced.

Comment: Subclassing built-in / base classes to get a specific behavior's well-defined and robust. General rules of thumb: don't change more than you have to; make sure the doc string describes purpose and behavior; add unit tests to cover the common desired & error conditions, as well as a few edge cases. https://towardsdatascience.com/python-tricks-inheriting-from-built-in-data-types-f6cbeb8d88a5 has some examples. One difficulty is that you can't see the source code for built-in types, so `__or__()` might return either a new `Set` or `self.__class__`. Testing will clarify what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just subclass `frozenset` and assert its length is 1.

```py
class Singleton(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, data):
        obj = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, data)
        assert len(obj) == 1, "Must be of length 1"
        return obj
```

But that is literally a just going to be a `frozenset` of length 1.

```py
x = Singleton([1])
print(x)
# Singleton({1})

print(Singleton([1]) | {2, 3})
# frozenset({1, 2, 3})

print(Singleton([1]) | Singleton([2]))
# frozenset({1, 2})

y = Singleton([1, 2])
# AssertionError: Must be of length 1
```

Not sure how useful the object would be, as most operations with `Singleton` operands are not going to be `Singleton`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. May I ask why you use `__new__` instead of `__init__`?

Comment: Because `frozenset()` is an immutable type and it can only be initialized upon creation. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859129/python-and-python-c-api-new-versus-init), asking the difference between `__new__` and `__init__`.