# how to create an immutable object in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering, if I do not create setters in my class definition, then essentially I can create an immutable object following the class model, right? What do you think? There might be other ways to go also.

Comment: No, you cannot because I can always add properties to an object of your class without at anytime. The question is why do you think you need a immutable object?

Comment: can you give us some code and concepts you were kicking around?  This might be something worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996815/ways-to-make-a-class-immutable-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an immutable object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828080/how-to-make-an-immutable-object-in-python)