# Creating inmutable types in Python using __new__()

Tags: python, datamodel

My question is pretty simple, I have:

```
class upperstr(str):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return str.__new__(cls, str(arg).upper())
```

Why, if my `__new__()` method is directly using an instance of an inmutable type (str), instances of my new type (upperstr) are mutable?

```
>>> s = str("text")
>>> "__dict__" in dir(s)
False
>>> s = upperstr("text")
>>> "__dict__" in dir(s)
True
```

In what stage does the interpreter sets the __dict__ attribute to upperstr intances if I'm only overriding the __new__() method?

Thanks!

Comment: "Has `__dict__`" does **not** imply "is mutable".

Comment: Related: [How to make an immutable object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828080/how-to-make-an-immutable-object-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All user-defined classes in Python have a `__dict__()` attribute by default, even if you don't overwrite anything at all:

```
>>> x = object()
>>> x.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     pass 
... 
>>> x = MyObject()
>>> x.__dict__
{}
```

If you don't want a new-style class to have a `__dict__`, use `__slots__` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots), [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots)):

```
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     __slots__ = []
... 
>>> x = MyObject()
>>> x.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyObject' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```