# Overriding tuple.__len__ in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, slice

I would like to implement an immutable type in python natively. I gathered from here

[How to make an immutable object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828080/how-to-make-an-immutable-object-in-python)

that the best way is to override tuple. Let's say I want a tuple that stores some extra data. I would do something like:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, lst, data):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, tuple(lst) + (data, ))
```

Now I would like to override the len function:

```
    def __len__(self):
        return tuple.__len__(self) - 1
```

This worked fine with my python version at home (Python 2.something, but I don't know which), but on my office computer (Python 2.7.3) it breaks slicing: If I do

```
m = MyTuple([1,2], 0)
print(m[:-1])
```

I get `(1, )` while at home I would get `(1, 2)` (I didn't actually check, but tracing my problem back to this minimal example, I think so). So it seems in one implementation, slicing is calling `tuple.__len__` while in the other it is calling `MyTuple.__len__`. I wouldn't mind either way, but consistency would be good.

So my question is: is there a robust solution and if not, which of the behaviors is going to be the stable one?

Edit: as Leonardo.Z suggested, my "home" python was actually Python 3(.4). I had been trying a new ide and not paid attention to which Python it used.

Comment: I am sure the Python version in your home is 3, not 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by a difference between the slice implementation of Python2 and Python3.

In Python3, `obj[x:y]` always equals `obj.__getitem__(slice(x,y))`. But in Python2, due to historical reasons, some built-in types(including tuple) implement the slice operator with the `__getslice__` method.

`__getslice__` uses the `__len__` method, `__getitem__` does not.

Just run the following code in Python2 and Python3, and you'll see why.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, lst, data):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, tuple(lst) + (data, ))
    def __len__(self):
        return tuple.__len__(self) - 1

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("__getitem__() is called.  start:%s, end:%s" % (key.start, key.stop))
        return super(MyTuple, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __getslice__(self, start, end):
        print("__getslice__() is called.  start:%s, end:%s" % (start,end))
        return super(MyTuple, self).__getslice__(start,end)

m = MyTuple([1,2], 0)

print(m[:-1])
```

According to the Python official doc, you should override `__getslice__()` method when you change then `__len__` implementation in your subclass.
Reference:

[The official doc about `object.__getslice__`.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__)

Answer (score 1):

Slicing does not necessarily relate to calling `__len__()`, especially not with built-in types.

`m[:-1]` translates to `m.__getitem__(slice(None, -1))`, which might be handled in the `tuple` type in a very easy way by calling an internal length function which iggnores the fact that `__len__` is overridden.

[Here](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/ba31940588b6/Objects/tupleobject.c#l701) is how the function is internally defined.

It seems that it makes extensive use of `PyTuple_GET_SIZE()`. I didn't find its definition, but I suppose it is defined quite simply.

Comment: `PyTuple_GET_SIZE` is defined in [`tupleobject.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a6f0aaeb96a/Include/tupleobject.h) as an alias for `Py_SIZE`, which reads the standard `ob_size` entry in the [`PyObject_VAR_HEAD` struct](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a6f0aaeb96a/Include/object.h#l90).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thx, now I found it, and so it does, so it indeed bypasses calling `__len__()` altogether.