# Copying an instance of a custom class on assignment in Python

Tags: python, class, copy, mutable

Is it possible in Python to copy an object of a custom class on assignment?

Meaning,

```
a = b
```

would effectively do

```
a = copy.copy(b)
```

, where a is a new variable, and b an instance of the custom class.

I guess there might be a customization function such as `__assign__`, but i didn't find anything in the operator-to-function table at the bottom of [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) page.

Comment: No, you can't customise assignment. What's the problem you're actually trying to solve? Should the instances just be immutable?

Comment: I don't want changes on immutable attributes of `b` be reflected in `a`'s attributes, which is why i need to copy the object. The class simply describes the position in a bitstream, so at a first glance it seems to be an integer, making it a popular source for bugs when assigning (and later comparing) instances of the class. Sorry for the duplicate, searched for the wrong keywords apparently.

Comment: My point is that you don't *need* to copy the object - if *the instance itself* is immutable, then when you change `a` that won't alter `b` and vice-versa. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4828080/3001761

Comment: But if the instance itself is immutable, i won't be able to modify its attributes at all, or did i get something wrong? I definitely need to modify the attributes.

Comment: No, you wouldn't, that's the whole point of immutability; instead, any "changes" actually create a new object the new attributes. If you need mutable objects, then you will have to explicitly copy them.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your help.