# How to provide value validation at abstract class level?

Tags: validation, python-3.x, setter, python-decorators

I have an ABC BaseAbstract class with several getter/setter properties defined.

I want to require that the value to be set is an `int` and from 0 - 15.

```
@luminance.setter
@abstractproperty
@ValidateProperty(Exception, types=(int,), valid=lambda x: True if 0 <= x <= 15 else False)
def luminance(self, value):
    """
    Set a value that indicate the level of light emitted from the block

    :param value: (int): 0 (darkest) - 15 (brightest)
    :return:
    """
    pass
```

Can someone help me figure out what my ValidateProperty class/method should look like. I started with a class and called the `accepts` method but this is causing an error:

> `function` object has no attribute 'func_code'

current source:

```
class ValidateProperty(object):
    @staticmethod
    def accepts(exception, *types, **kwargs):
        def check_accepts(f, **kwargs):
            assert len(types) == f.func_code.co_argcount

            def new_f(*args, **kwds):
                for i, v in enumerate(args):
                    if f.func_code.co_varnames[i] in types and\
                            not isinstance(v, types[f.func_code.co_varnames[i]]):
                        arg = f.func_code.co_varnames[i]
                        exp = types[f.func_code.co_varnames[i]]
                        raise exception("arg '{arg}'={r} does not match {exp}".format(arg=arg,
                                                                                      r=v,
                                                                                      exp=exp))
                        # del exp       (unreachable)

                    for k,v in kwds.__iter__():
                        if k in types and not isinstance(v, types[k]):
                            raise exception("arg '{arg}'={r} does not match {exp}".format(arg=k,
                                                                                          r=v,
                                                                                          exp=types[k]))

                    return f(*args, **kwds)

            new_f.func_name = f.func_name
            return new_f

        return check_accepts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of us is confused about how [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489720/208880), [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) (e.g. properties), and [abstracts](https://pymotw.com/2/abc/) work -- I hope it's not me.  ;)

Here is a rough working example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class ValidateProperty:
    def __init__(inst, exception, arg_type, valid):
        # called on the @ValidateProperty(...) line
        #
        # save the exception to raise, the expected argument type, and
        # the validator code for later use
        inst.exception = exception
        inst.arg_type = arg_type
        inst.validator = valid
    def __call__(inst, func):
        # called after the def has finished, but before it is stored
        #
        # func is the def'd function, save it for later to be called
        # after validating the argument
        def check_accepts(self, value):
            if not inst.validator(value):
                raise inst.exception('value %s is not valid' % value)
            func(self, value)
        return check_accepts

class AbstractTestClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractproperty
    def luminance(self):
        # abstract property
        return
    @luminance.setter
    @ValidateProperty(Exception, int, lambda x: 0 <= x <= 15)
    def luminance(self, value):
        # abstract property with validator
        return

class TestClass(AbstractTestClass):
    # concrete class
    val = 7
    @property
    def luminance(self):
        # concrete property
        return self.val
    @luminance.setter
    def luminance(self, value):
        # concrete property setter
        # call base class first to activate the validator
        AbstractTestClass.__dict__['luminance'].__set__(self, value)
        self.val = value

tc = TestClass()
print(tc.luminance)
tc.luminance = 10
print(tc.luminance)
tc.luminance = 25
print(tc.luminance)
```

Which results in:

```
7
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abstract.py", line 47, in <module>
    tc.luminance = 25
  File "abstract.py", line 40, in luminance
    AbstractTestClass.__dict__['luminance'].__set__(self, value)
  File "abstract.py", line 14, in check_accepts
    raise inst.exception('value %s is not valid' % value)
Exception: value 25 is not valid
```

A few points to think about:

- The `ValidateProperty` is much simpler because a property setter only takes two parameters: `self` and the `new_value`
- When using a `class` for a decorator, and the decorator takes arguments, then you will need `__init__` to save the parameters, and `__call__` to actually deal with the `def`d function
- Calling a base class property setter is ugly, but you could hide that in a helper function
- you might want to use a custom metaclass to ensure the validation code is run (which would also avoid the ugly base-class property call)

---

I suggested a metaclass above to eliminate the need for a direct call to the base class's `abstractproperty`, and here is an example of such:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class AbstractTestClassMeta(ABCMeta):

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict):
        # create new class
        new_cls = super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict)
        # collect all base class dictionaries
        base_dicts = [b.__dict__ for b in bases]
        if not base_dicts:
            return new_cls
        # iterate through clsdict looking for properties
        for name, obj in clsdict.items():
            if not isinstance(obj, (property)):
                continue
            prop_set = getattr(obj, 'fset')
            # found one, now look in bases for validation code
            validators = []
            for d in base_dicts:
                b_obj = d.get(name)
                if (
                        b_obj is not None and
                        isinstance(b_obj.fset, ValidateProperty)
                        ):
                    validators.append(b_obj.fset)
            if validators:
                def check_validators(self, new_val):
                    for func in validators:
                        func(new_val)
                    prop_set(self, new_val)
                new_prop = obj.setter(check_validators)
                setattr(new_cls, name, new_prop)

        return new_cls
```

This subclasses `ABCMeta`, and has `ABCMeta` do all of its work first, then does some additional processing.  Namely:

- go through the created class and look for properties
- check the base classes to see if they have a matching abstractproperty
- check the abstractproperty's `fset` code to see if it is an instance of `ValidateProperty`
- if so, save it in a list of validators
- if the list of validators is not empty

  - make a wrapper that will call each validator before calling the actual property's `fset` code
  - replace the found property with a new one that uses the wrapper as the `setter` code

`ValidateProperty` is a little different as well:

```
class ValidateProperty:

    def __init__(self, exception, arg_type):
        # called on the @ValidateProperty(...) line
        #
        # save the exception to raise and the expected argument type
        self.exception = exception
        self.arg_type = arg_type
        self.validator = None

    def __call__(self, func_or_value):
        # on the first call, func_or_value is the function to use
        # as the validator
        if self.validator is None:
            self.validator = func_or_value
            return self
        # every subsequent call will be to do the validation
        if (
                not isinstance(func_or_value, self.arg_type) or
                not self.validator(None, func_or_value)
                ):
            raise self.exception(
                '%r is either not a type of %r or is outside '
                'argument range' %
                (func_or_value, type(func_or_value))
                )
```

The base `AbstractTestClass` now uses the new `AbstractTestClassMeta`, and has the validator code directly in the `abstractproperty`:

```
class AbstractTestClass(metaclass=AbstractTestClassMeta):

    @abstractproperty
    def luminance(self):
        # abstract property
        pass

    @luminance.setter
    @ValidateProperty(Exception, int)
    def luminance(self, value):
        # abstract property validator
        return 0 <= value <= 15
```

The final class is the same:

```
class TestClass(AbstractTestClass):
    # concrete class

    val = 7

    @property
    def luminance(self):
        # concrete property
        return self.val

    @luminance.setter
    def luminance(self, value):
        # concrete property setter
        # call base class first to activate the validator
        # AbstractTestClass.__dict__['luminance'].__set__(self, value)
        self.val = value
```

Comment: The confusion probably rests with me. I am venturing into the more esoteric and advanced areas of Python (which is where I'm having the most fun).

I'll work with your solution. I am interested in the suggestion to use a custom metaclass. Can you provide a link on that bullet for a good starting point? I would like to avoid the call to the base class property setter.

Comment: BTW, I am wondering what raised a red flag regarding any confusion on the topic so I know where I might be confused. :) Can you edit w/ a short explanation? Much appreciated.

Comment: @IAbstract: It was your `ValidateProperty` decorator, which wasn't a correct decorator for a regular function, let alone for a method in a class (and a property, at that! ;).  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/208880) for a very good explanation on decorators in general.

Comment: @IAbstract: Here's [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32151625/208880) that deals lightly with metaclasses (see the bottom half).  I'll try to sketch out a validating abstract meta class here in the next few days.

Comment: @IAbstract: Just noticed you had this tagged as Python 3 -- I updated the answer (had been using Python 2 syntax).

Comment: Okay, so I don't need `(object)` when defining a class?

Comment: @IAbstract: No, because in Python 3 *everything* is based on `object`.  The other change was specifying the metaclass in the header instead of in the body.

Comment: Wow!!! Okay, I'm really seeing the power of the abstract metaclass. Wonderful work!