# Kivy - I can't change .source with an id

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language

I want to change my picture in a box, I am trying to do that with the help of id's. I have tried many solutions and have search for well over 3 hours but I couldn't get anything right so I would be grateful for any help. I am also quite new to Kivy.

I tried changing:

```
self.ids.rec.source = 'download.jpg'
```

to(as suggested by [Python - Kivy: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' when trying to get self.ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074550/python-kivy-attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-getattr-whe))

```
self.parent.parent.ids
```

It did not work, only changed my error to:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Tried to fiddle with it on my own but also couldn't really do much except change the error to an another one.

This is my python file:

```
from kivy.app import *
from kivy.uix.button import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.widget import *
from kivy.uix.label import *
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import *
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import *
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty,ObjectProperty
x = []
f = []
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Picture(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Picture, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def change(self,**kwargs):
        y = len(x)
        if y % 2 == 0:
            self.ids.rec.source = 'download.jpg'
            tilesource = 'download.jpg'
            print("aaaa")
        else:
            tilesource = 'images.jpg'
            print("bbbbb")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TileWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TileWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos = (0, 0)
        self.size = (1,1)
        d = Picture()
        self.add_widget(d)

    def swap(self):
        x.append("0")
        Picture().change()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class langApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TileWidget()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    langApp().run()


And this is my .kv file:

    #:kivy 1.11.1
<TileWidget>:
    FloatLayout:
        pos: 0,0
        size: root.width,root.height
        Button:
            text: 'Last'
            pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1
        Button:
            text: 'Stop'
            pos_hint: {'x':.45,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1
        Button:
            on_press: root.swap()
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint: {'x':.65,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1
<Picture>:
    pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.4}
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            id: rec
            size: self.size[0]*0.5,self.size[1]*0.5
            pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1]
            source: "images.jpg"
```

Here is my full error log:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'rec'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/Leon/mobile/main.py", line 45, in <module>
     langApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Leon\mobile\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "c:\Users\Leon\mobile\lang.kv", line 15, in <module>
     on_press: root.swap()
   File "c:/Users/Leon/mobile/main.py", line 37, in swap
     Picture().change()
   File "c:/Users/Leon/mobile/main.py", line 19, in change
     self.ids.rec.source = 'download.jpg'
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

The `swap()` method:

```
def swap(self):
    x.append("0")
    Picture().change()
```

is creating a new instance of `Picture` and calling `change()` on that new instance. That will have no effect on the instance of `Picture` that is actually in your GUI. An easy way to fix that is to keep a reference to the `Picture` instance that is actually in your GUI, and use that in the `swap()` method:

```
class TileWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TileWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos = (0, 0)
        self.size = (1,1)
        self.d = Picture()
        self.add_widget(self.d)

    def swap(self):
        x.append("0")
        self.d.change()
```

The second problem is that you cannot use `ids` for canvas instructions, but you can use `groups`. So, you can place the `Rectangle` instruction in a group of its own:

```
<Picture>:
    pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.4}
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            group: 'rec'  # place this instruction in its own group
            size: self.size[0]*0.5,self.size[1]*0.5
            pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1]
            source: "images.jpg"
```

Then you can use that `group` to modify the `Rectangle`:

```
def change(self,**kwargs):
    y = len(x)
    if y % 2 == 0:
        rec = self.canvas.get_group('rec')[0]
        rec.source = 'download.jpg'
        tilesource = 'download.jpg'
        print("aaaa")
    else:
        tilesource = 'images.jpg'
        print("bbbbb")
```