# Defining a class inside a loop causes a memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import gc
import resource
import time

gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL)

while True:
    class A():
        pass

    print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
    print("Garbage: ", len(gc.garbage))
    print("Collected: ", gc.collect())
    time.sleep(1)
```

and when i run it for a few iterations, i get the following:

```
9916
Garbage:  0
Collected:  0
9916
Garbage:  0
Collected:  5
9916
Garbage:  5
Collected:  5
9916
Garbage:  10
Collected:  5
9916
Garbage:  15
Collected:  5
```

As we can see, the garbage in memory starts to grow and the garbage collector can't collect the allocated memory. As a result, we have just created a memory leak.

My question is why this memory leak happens?

Does it have to do with the way class definitions are stored in the heap?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I'm not able to reproduce this in Python 2.7

Comment: I don't believe class definitions have a reference counter for object instances. They are probably never fully cleared so that any remaining object instance can still find its definition.   Given that this is definition, not data, I don't see a big issue with it.  Scenarios where you would dynamically redefine classes (let alone in a loop) aren't your typical use case.

Comment: Its interesting to add `for x in gc.garbage: print(id(x), type(x), x)`

Comment: @AlainT. - object instances reference their class with `self.__class__` and that bumps the refcount.

Comment: Interesting post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787603/what-exactly-is-weakref-in-python. It seems like python is keeping a weakref to the class each time it is rebuilt in the loop. Its looking like a memory leak to me and worth a bug report. If class definitions within a function are allowed, they should operate sanely.

Comment: Each time you define `A` you create a new type and types don't go away.

Comment: I filed a bug report in 
https://bugs.python.org/issue40292.
The ticket was closed as it is expected behavior of gc.set_debug