# Dir function on classes in python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why when I create a class in Python for example:

```
class My:
```

and when I `print(dir(python))` it returns a list of functions and attributes in which there is a `__weakref__` method,

so my questions is from where did this method appear if the class that I create inherits from object class which doesn't have this method

Comment: The Python runtime adds it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

These methods (the ones starting with double underscore) are called **dunder** methods.See [more](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/find-all-methods-of-class) and this [**weakref**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788031/1138192)

These are usually called by a wrapper function. For example, the `dict()` function calls the `__dict__()` method.

we won’t be needing the double underscore prefixed methods, so we can filter them using the below snippet:

```
method_list = [method for method in dir(My) if not method.startswith('__')]
print(method_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

Comment: `something is False` is *usually* written `not something`...