# Immutable class and __copy__

Tags: python

For a class which is intended to be used as immutable, such as:

```
class Immutable:
    def __init__(self, field):
        self._field = field
    def field(self):
        return self._field
```

is it ok, to return `self` in `__copy__`?

```
    def __copy__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: Not a bit in the above code makes  this class immutable.

Comment: @DeepSpace of course, it's Python. That's why I said "intended to be used".

Comment: "of course, it's Python." There **are** ways to make a class immutable in Python.

Comment: @DeepSpace sure. Above example, named tuple subclass, custom `__setattr__`, ... whatever, is it ok to return `self` from `__copy__`?

Comment: No, the above example is not immutable at all. As such, it doesn't matter what `__copy__` returns.

Comment: @PM2Ring I thought `__copy__` is needed for `copy.copy()`... How does `copy.copy(tuple(...))` work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828080/how-to-make-an-immutable-object-in-python , especially the answer that mentions `__slots__`.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, that's exactly my question: `copy(tuple)` returns new object so I was wondering whether I should reuse `self` or do as tuple does, i.e. create new object with the same content?

Comment: @PM2Ring Btw., `copy.copy` seems to work even if I don't declare `__copy__` method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to make it so that users of your class can safely call `copy.copy` on its instances, then by all means feel free to add a `__copy__` method:

```
def __copy__(self): 
    return self
```

However, this isn't really necessary. The documentation for your class should make it clear that its instances are immutable, so anyone using your class should know that they can safely re-use an instance if they want to refer to it in multiple places, just like they do with the built-in immutable types like `int`, `str`, `tuple`, and `frozenset`. Eg,

```
a, b, c = Immutable(123), Immutable(456), 42
d = {'one': a, 'two': b, 'three': c}
```

If you don't supply a `__copy__` method and someone *does* call `copy.copy` on an instance, then they'll get a new object that's a clone of the original instance. With `__copy__` defined as above they will of course just get a reference to the original object.

BTW, you should make `.field` (and any other attributes) into a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), and don't supply a setter.

```
class Immutable:
    def __init__(self, field):
        self._field = field

    @property
    def field(self):
        return self._field
```

And now you can call the field method as if it were a simple attribute:

```
a = Immutable(123) 
print(a.field)
```

Of course, you can still mutate the `._field` attribute in the normal way, but anyone using your class ought to know they aren't supposed to do that. :)

---

In the question comments we discussed the fact that calling `copy.copy` on a tuple returns a reference to the original tuple, even though `tuple` doesn't define `__copy__`. None of the built-in types define `__copy__`, but bear in mind that they are all defined in C, so they work a little differently to classes defined in Python. FWIW, calling `copy.copy` on any of the built-in immutable types returns a reference to the original object, and calling `copy.copy` on any of the built-in mutable types returns a clone.