# Making compound objects immutable in Python

Tags: python, copy, immutability

Is there a way to make a **compound** Python object immutable ‘in-depth’? That is, to disallow any change at any level to the object.

One can indeed make a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of the object to work with, but that can be costly. I'd like to see if one can make the compound object completely immutable, perhaps by recursively overriding the internal [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) methods to emulate immutability.

An example would be a dictionary which has dictionaries and Numpy arrays as its values, or a Numpy array which stores Python objects as its elements.

This is related to the SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4828080), “How to make an immutable object in Python?”.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I don't see the use case for this.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: A use-case for me is to share _concurrently_ a (heavy) compound Python object between _more than one_ user-provided functions. The functions should not be able to mutate the objects in any way, in order to prevent data corruption.

Comment: Fair enough. It definitely won't be easy though. Making mutable objects immutable isn't something you usually need to do; you'd generally make the classes immutable to begin with.