# Is it possible to freeze a dataclass object in __post_init__() or later?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm wondering whether it's possible to "freeze" a dataclass object in **post_init**() or even after an object was defined.

So instead of:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ClassName:
    var1: type = value
```

Having something like:

```
@dataclass
class ClassName:
     var1: type = None
def __post_init__(self):
     self.var1 = value
     FREEZE()
```

Or even sth like:

```
a = ClassName()
FREEZE(a)
```

Possible or not and why?

Comment: You might just want to do what's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119384/10863327).  Also you could make `var1` a `property` instead of a field.

Comment: At this time, setting `frozen=True` modifies how the `class` statement ultimately executed with `exec` is defined; it's not simply an attribute of the class. What's your reason for wanting to delay immutability?

Comment: What would be the point of this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Currently the variables are treated as properties and it works, however this way of assignment might not be straightforward for the user after release.

Comment: So if immutability could be delayed, the variables could be assigned in a clearer fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't. But "frozen" can be subverted trivially, just use:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ClassName:
     var1: type = value
def __post_init__(self):
    object.__setattr__(self, 'var1', value)
```