# How to create a copy of an immutable object and update some properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined an immutable class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828108/3423035). Now I'd like to define a copy method that transfers all properties of a given instance to a new instance and that allows to provide new values for any of the existing properties.

This is what I have:

```
from operator import itemgetter

class Foo(tuple):
    __slots__ = []

    def __new__(cls, a, b, c):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (a, b, c))

    a = property(itemgetter(0))
    b = property(itemgetter(1))
    c = property(itemgetter(2))

    def copy(self, a='', b='', c=''):
        return Foo(
            a=a if a else self.a,
            b=b if b else self.b,
            c=c if c else self.c,
        )
```

Desired behaviour:

```
instance_a = Foo('a', 'b', 'c')
instance_b = instance_a.copy(c='d')

assert instance_b.a == 'a'
assert instance_b.b == 'b'
assert instance_b.c == 'd'
```

**Question**:
Is there a more elegant way to pick between the new and existing properties other than the `if else` construct (i.e., `a=a if a else self.a`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) in the standard library does the same thing and has a convenient copy method called `_replace` too:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ('a', 'b', 'c'))

x = Foo(1, 2, 3)
print(x)
y = x._replace(b='hello')
print(y)
```

outputs

```
Foo(a=1, b=2, c=3)
Foo(a=1, b='hello', c=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know of `_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

`a or self.a`
But if `bool(a)` is evaluated to `False` it will have unexpected behaviour. But it is already the case in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a bit cleaner!