# Why does Python allows object reference to call __init__() even after object is created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class student:
    ''' Doc String for student class'''
    clgname='#########'
    def __init__(self,name,rNo,branch):
        self.name=name
        self.rNo=rNo
        self.branch=branch
        return None
    @classmethod
    def classMethodexp(cls):
        cls.clgname='halva clg'

if __name__=='__main__':
    obj=student(name='Halv',branch='ece',rNo=12345)
    print(obj.__dict__)
    obj.__init__(name='******',branch='ece',rNo=12345)
    print(obj.__dict__)
```

**output:**

```
{'name': 'Halv', 'rNo': 12345, 'branch': 'ece'}
{'name': '******', 'rNo': 12345, 'branch': 'ece'}
```

I heard a few languages don't allow constructor call once an object is created, then why does Python allow it??

Comment: `why python allows it??` - Because it does?

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Why? → Because there's no need to explicitly disallow that. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Because objects in Python are mutable and you can change the attributes. See this question to make objects immutable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828080/how-to-make-an-immutable-object-in-python

Comment: This is what makes *inheritence* possible.  You call parent class' `__init__` method to initialize your child class.

Comment: Why not? What is the problem with calling the `__init__` hook again?

Comment: @Asocia well, that would be distinct from the OPs example. In inheritance, typically, distinct `__init__`s are called each only once

Comment: Note, in Python, `__init__` is technically an "initializer", whereas `__new__` is a constructor, or rather, object construction involves both