# Extend immutable (frozen) dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I found the use of a frozen dataclass the most clean solution to [make Python objects immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992808/5316326). The implementation is really simple adding a single class decorator:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Immutable:
    attr1: int
    attr2: int
```

Now I want to extend the `Immutable` class by introducing a new attribute `attr3`:

```py
class MyImmutableChild(Immutable):
    attr3: int
```

But, the behavior is not as expected:

```py
>>> immutable_obj = MyImmutableChild(attr1=1, attr2=3, attr3=5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2b6c18366721> in <module>
----> 1 immutable_obj = MyImmutableChild(attr1=1, attr2=3, attr3=5)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attr3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this is simply solved by adding another `@dataclass(frozen=True)` decorator to the child class