Are these built-in types mutable or not?
In Python some type is called mutable if it is possible to change the value of any object of this type (without changing the identity of the object).
Which of the following built-in types are mutable, and which of them are immutable? And why?

function (in particular, method)
module (here I mean the type of the imported module, e.g. the command import sys; type(sys) returns <class 'module'>)
file type (for example, _io.TextIOWrapper)

The official reference says the following here:

Unlike function objects, code objects are immutable and contain no references (directly or indirectly) to mutable objects.

I think this implies that functions are mutable because function objects can contain references (directly or indirectly) to mutable objects. Also it is always possible to change the code of a function object without affecting its id (see example here).

"this implies that functions are mutable because function objects can contain references (directly or indirectly) to mutable objects" - functions are mutable because functions are mutable, you can e.g. add arbitrary attributes to them (common in memoization, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268784/3001761). User-defined classes are by definition not built-in types, and you can certainly define your own immutable things if needed (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4828080/3001761) so whether their instances are or not depends on the author.

Everything you listed is at least potentially mutable
User-defined functions are mutable, you can assign attributes to them, e.g.
def foo():
    pass

foo.bar = 1  # Completely legal

Methods are just functions that happen to implement the descriptor protocol and are attached to a class, so they become bound methods when accessed via an instance of the class, so user-defined methods are just as mutable as functions. Even without that, functions can contain references to mutable default arguments, e.g.:
def foo(x, unsafe_list=[]):
    unsafe_list.append(x)

stores the default unsafe_list argument in the function object, and mutates it each time the function is called.
Built-in functions implemented in C tend not to be mutable, simply because they lack a __dict__ to store arbitrary attributes unless they opt-in explicitly, and don't have the same default argument handling, but they can opt-in to arbitrary attributes (functools.partial does so specifically to ensure it continues to work like a user-defined function so wrapping a user-defined function with functools.partial doesn't break that functionality).
Modules are also mutable, for the same reason; they all have a dictionary (which holds all the variables, functions, classes, etc. defined in them) which you can modify by simple assignment to attributes of the imported module.
File-like objects are mutable by definition; they have state (the file pointer) that is modified merely by reading them, and for the ones that support seek, you can manually adjust that file pointer rather than just advancing it implicitly via read, iteration, etc.

The method object returned by function.__get__ (the bound method), however, is immutable. (II think; you can't add attributes, and its __self__ and __func__ attributes are read-only.).

One thing left that still confuses me: Python glossary says that "Mutable objects can change their value but keep their id()." I think that in case of such built-in types as list or bytearray we can replace the term "value" in the glossary definition with repr(object). But how should we interpret the term "value" in case of function/module/file object? If we interpret this term as repr(object), then these three objects will turn out to be immutable objects (e.g. assigning attributes to the function obj doesn't change its repr).

@Rodvi: repr is utterly irrelevant here. Some things don't have useful/complete reprs, you can't derive any useful information about mutability from that. "value" means any observable state of the object. vars(function_or_module_name) will get the underlying dict storing the (mutable) attributes. fileobj.tell() will report new values when advanced, and merely iterating a file object will show new values each time, clearly it's got state that changes.

@chepner: What's funny is that bound methods actually have the ability to set arbitrary attributes, but they seem to have blocked it while still giving it a __dict__, so you can set them in a weird way, then access them normally. If you make a class Foo with a method bar, then do b = Foo().bar, b.x = 1 fails, but vars(b)['x'] = 1 works just fine, and afterwards, b.x returns 1, so they are mutable, they just blocked the normal means of setting attributes.

@ShadowRanger I'm not even going to try to think of a rationale for that design :)

@chepner: Now that I think about it, I suspect they blocked direct assignment to avoid the confusion of someone with f = Foo() doing f.bar.x = 1, which would "work", but because the bound method is ephemeral, it would cease to exist along with the newly assigned attribute immediately (so reading f.bar.x would fail). Allowing assignment via the __dict__ is still unsafe (vars(f.bar)['x'] = 1 would be equally broken), but they left it as an option since you're highly unlikely to do it by accident, unlike f.bar.x = 1, and there are rare cases it might be useful.
